# Complicated Nested Excel Function

Tags: excel

I'm working on a function in Excel that will allow me to sum columns if the column before it contains the word "pre"

here's a mock spreadsheet:

```
                   Grade          Points Possible

C++ Pre Test         20                   20
Homework Week 1      30                   30
C++ Test             90                  100
```

Now I want to use the SUMIF() function with a SEARCH() function nested in it that will examine cells A2 through A4 and if the word 'pre' is found it will sum the appropriate number in column B.

Here's what I have so far that doesn't seem to be working:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A4,SEARCH("pre",A2:A4),B2:B4)
```

What I intend for this to say is "If the word 'pre' is found in any cell in the range a2:a4, pull the value from its corresponding grade in column b". The output I am expecting with the mock spreadsheet is '20' since pre only appears once.

Perhaps a VB macro would be in order?

EDIT: Upon further investigation maybe the LOOKUP() function may be best suited since SEARCH() is used to return a value from the column it's searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=SUMIF(A2:A4, "=*pre*",B2:B4)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved what I was going for and in my more complex actual spreadsheet it ended up in an average function like so:

    =AVERAGE(SUMIF(A4:A100,"=*pre*",B4:B100),COUNTIF(A4:A100,"=*pre*"))

Comment: Seen in the introduction of an MS Excel macro training book in 1991: "The best macro is no macro". So true...

Answer (score 1):

The above will not work.    If the array more than 2 (I know it is) you can extend this on up to 30 iterations for the sumproduct function

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2*IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(" Pre ",A2)),0,1),B3*IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(" Pre ",A3)),0,1))
```

I do not really see any difference if you use `sum` or `sumproduct` and while 30 is the max, you just do multiples like `=SUM() + SUM()` would make 60.

Another option is to use column `C` and inert this into `C1` and copy it on down

`=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(" Pre ",A1)),"",B1)`

and sum at the end.

Next option is as you mention - a macro with a rolling sum using for i, next i

Answer (score 0):

Take apart your formula.

`=Search("Pre",A2)` returns 5 - I don't think you want that in your sumif.

Try this instead:

Create a new column `D` that looks for the word "pre" in column `A`.  Maybe something like `=iferror(Search("Pre",A2),1,0))`  [If Pre exists in that cell, return 1, else return 0]

Now `sumproduct(B:B,D:D)` should give you points earned on pretests, and `sumproduct(C:C,D:D)` should give you points possible.